# Composition of functions to the nth time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, finance

I am trying to create an equation that shows me how long it will take with an annual withdrawal taken from compounded interest in a present value. I am stuck because I am wanting to take the composition of a function n times until my remaining value is zero or less than zero: For example:

If your future value is determined by the equation:

$$
F(p)=1.05p
$$

In dollars.

You then take a fixed amount each year, $w=100$ after interest has been compounded. I then am stuck by having to take the composition of a function of itself until the $F(p) \leq 0$

Long Version:

$$
F(1000)=1050; 1050-w= 950
$$

$$
F(950)=997.5; 997.5-w=897.5
$$

$$
F(897.5) = 942.38; 942.38-w= 842.38
$$

So on and so forth, that leads me to my wall that I hit. I feel to express this correctly i have to use $F(F(p)-w)-w$ n times. Can someone please help me with this thought process?

How can I express this mathematical dilemma?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316915 for a way to deal with the problem.

Comment: @DavidK thank you that is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define recurrence relation on the balance. $B_0$ is the beginning balance money and
$$B_n = f(B_{n-1}) - w$$
is the balance after $n$ withdrawals.

When $f$ is linear like multiplication as in your example, there is easy way to solve for explicit formula for $B_n$. When $f$ is not a simple function, I do not think there is a way. Suppose that $f(x) = ax$ with $a = 1.05$ in your example. We will try to find some $v$ such that
$$B_n - v = a(B_{n-1} - v)$$
Evidently, we must have
$$(a-1)v = w$$
so
$$v = \frac{w}{a-1}.$$

Now the sequence $C_n = B_n - v$ can be easily solved explicitly $C_n = a^n C_0$ which allows you to deduce
$$B_n = C_n + v = a^n (B_0 - v) + v.$$
Then solving for $n$ is a matter of solving equation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work out a problem like this is to suppose that at the very beginning,
you take the original balance of the account, $p$ and split it into $n$ smaller accounts: the first account will sit for a year and then you withdraw the entire amount; the second account will sit for two years and then you withdraw the entire amount; and so forth.
To make this match the original problem, we want the amount in the $k$th account to be just enough so that in $k$ years it grows to exactly the amount, $w$, that you need to withdraw at the end of the $k$th year.

At the interest rate of $5\%$ that is given in the question,
in order to withdraw $w$ after one year, the first account needs to start
with a balance of $\frac{w}{1.05}$.
In order to withdraw $w$ after two years, the second account needs to
start with $\frac{w}{1.05^2}$.
In general the $k$th account, which needs to grow to a balance of $w$
after $k$ years, must start with a balance of $\frac{w}{1.05^k}$.
So the original balance has to be split among $n$ accounts like this:

$$ p = \frac{w}{1.05} + \frac{w}{1.05^2} + \cdots + \frac{w}{1.05^{n-1}} + b $$

where $0 < b \leq \frac{w}{1.05^{n}}$, that is, $b$ is the amount in the last
account, which lets you withdraw an amount up to $w$ after $n$ years,
but not more (because if it were more, after withdrawing $w$ you would
still have money left over for year $n+1$).

You may recognize the sum in the equation above as a geometric series with
the initial term $\frac{w}{1.05}$ and ratio $\frac{1}{1.05}$.
You can express this in a closed form, then find the maximum value of $n$
for which the sum is less than the initial value $p$.